# My character's shape has changed

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I have a problem. When I transferred my character and his armor to Unity, there were distortions in his shape. To solve this, I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> in Blender, but this time the positions of his fingers and arms changed.

What should I do to solve my problem?

[image: My character in Unity]

[image: My character in Blender]

Comment: hello, maybe a bon orientation, try a Ctrl R 180 on the arm in Edit mode

Comment: It didn't work. By the way, it's not just the arms that are crooked, but the legs that are crooked.

Comment: "*I did Ctrl + A in Blender*" is vague. What did you do exactly?  What kind of distortions do you see and what do you expect instead?